# msg file needed?

Tags: ros, publisher, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello reader,

do i need a msg-file when i want to write a publisher and a subscriber?
and if yes, how do i have to integrate the file into the publisher-code and the subscriber-code?

thx in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42533/msg-file-needed?/) by [shane](https://answers.ros.org/users/3039/shane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shane](https://answers.ros.org/users/3039/shane/) on 2012-08-28**:
and what if i want to publish an 1 dimensional array? do i just need to include "std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.h" or do i need something else?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-28**:
You can use Float64MultiArray but it might be a bit tricky because you need to give a layout definition. Have a look at the message definitions for more info. They contain some documentation. I personally think that Float64MultiArray doesn't provide enough semantics and I'd define my own message.

**Comment by [shane](https://answers.ros.org/users/3039/shane/) on 2012-08-28**:
hm, i see.
and what do i write into my own defined message?
double arrayname[4]?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-28**:
Depends on what you want to send around. Have a look at [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg) for data types you can use.

**Comment by [shane](https://answers.ros.org/users/3039/shane/) on 2012-08-28**:
i want to send a 1-dim double array with the size of 4

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-29**:
It would be `float64 arrayname[4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorials and the wiki are always a good starting point. Have a look at [this](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Concepts) wiki page and [this](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29), [this](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) and [this](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages) tutorial.

You always need a message file to generate the C++ files that define the types you need for subscribing and publishing. For instance `std_msgs/msg/String.msg` is used to generate `std_msgs/String.h` which is for instance used in the above tutorials. ROS provides a lot of pre-defined messages and if you can, you should use them. If you cannot find a matching message, you need to define it yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5